# Can I use intellisense with plain HTML? No asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, mobile

I have the following problem:
My site works perfectly, yet but on mobile.

There are 2 problems:
When I start up my site, it appears to not be responsive. Or at least, not really ...
It also gives me the problem: untellisense undefined.
I think these 2 problems should be connected? Although, I have no idea why ...
When I make my screen smaller and bigger, it's no problem. Only when I switch to iPad/iPhone/Mobile it goes all crazy.

This might be important as wel, I use bootstrap to get everything responsive. Does bootstrap need intellisense to run correctly?

Here's the code of my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Glow In The Dark</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.gallery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>
    <script src="js/_references.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
    $('#dg-container').gallery({
     autoplay : true
    });
   });
    </script>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
    <!--Code voor facebookpage te embedden-->
    <!--vanaf hier site-->

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse nospace navbar-fixed-top" id="home">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <img alt="Brand" src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive navbar-left" style="width: 87px; height:50px;">
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#headpic">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#line-up">Line-up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tickets">Tickets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    

    <section class="" id="headpic">
        <img src="img/FB.jpg" />
    </section>

    <section class="" id="intro">
        <div class="container cl">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-12" id="introtext">
                <img src="img/GITD.png" class="img-responsive col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" />
                <p class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">'Glow In The Dark' is een party concept gevestigd in Brugge. Het concept is al actief sinds 6 februari 2015. Ons belangrijkste doel is om de jongeren de avond van hun leven te geven.
Dit gaat gepaard met tal van blacklights, neon-verf, duizenden glowsticks en natuurlijk een indrukwekkende (inter)nationale line-up. Dit alles proberen wij te presenteren aan een zo schappelijk mogelijke prijs.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="img/woman.png" class="col-md-4 col- col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="woman" />
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-12" id="infobar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>Partypeople</p>
                    <h2>2410</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>Since</p>
                    <h2>16/02/2015</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>Edition</p>
                    <h2>4</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>Glowsticks used</p>
                    <h2>+16000</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="Gallery" id="Gallery">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Gallery</h1>
            <hr />
        </div>
        
        <section id="dg-container" class="dg-container">
            <div class="dg-wrapper">
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/One-Try-Film-Photography-520848987996024/photos/?tab=album&album_id=1106955852718665" class="" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transform: translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg);"><img src="img/image01.jpg" alt="image01"><div><!--Enter text here to go under image--></div></a>
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/LumenPhotos/photos/?tab=album&album_id=644309199067790" class="" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transform: translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg);"><img src="img/image02.jpg" alt="image02"><div><!--Enter text here to go under image--></div></a>
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/BruggeLeeft/photos/?tab=album&album_id=10154251768231418" class="" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transform: translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg);"><img src="img/image03.jpg" alt="image03"><div><!--Enter text here to go under image--></div></a>
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/RDCfotografie/photos/?tab=album&album_id=1452047338143203" class="" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transform: translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg);"><img src="img/image04.jpg" alt="image04"><div><!--Enter text here to go under image--></div></a>
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/BruggeLeeft/photos/?tab=album&album_id=10154251768231418" class="" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transform: translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg);"><img src="img/image05-2.jpg" alt="image05"><div><!--Enter text here to go under image--></div></a>
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/RDCfotografie/photos/?tab=album&album_id=1452047338143203" class="" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transform: translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg);"><img src="img/image06.jpg" alt="image06"><div><!--Enter text here to go under image--></div></a>
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/One-Try-Film-Photography-520848987996024/photos/?tab=album&album_id=1106955852718665" class="" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transform: translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg);"><img src="img/image07.jpg" alt="image07"><div><!--Enter text here to go under image--></div></a>
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/LumenPhotos/photos/?tab=album&album_id=644309199067790" class="" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transform: translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg);"><img src="img/image08.jpg" alt="image08"><div><!--Enter text here to go under image--></div></a>
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/BruggeLeeft/photos/?tab=album&album_id=10154251768231418" class="" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible; transform: translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg);"><img src="img/image09.jpg" alt="image09"><div><!--Enter text here to go under image--></div></a>
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/BruggeLeeft/photos/?tab=album&album_id=10154251768231418" class="dg-center" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible; transform: translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg);"><img src="img/image10.jpg" alt="image10"><div><!--Enter text here to go under image--></div></a>
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/RDCfotografie/photos/?tab=album&album_id=1452047338143203" class="" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible; transform: translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg);"><img src="img/image11.jpg" alt="image11"><div><!--Enter text here to go under image--></div></a>
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/LumenPhotos/photos/?tab=album&album_id=644309199067790" class="" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transform: translateX(450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(-45deg);"><img src="img/image12.jpg" alt="image12"><div><!--Enter text here to go under image--></div></a>
            </div>
            <!--nav>
            <span class="dg-prev">&lt;</span>
            <span class="dg-next">&gt;</span>
        </nav-->
        </section>
    </section>

    <section id="line-up" class="">

        <div class="col-md-12" id="ticketsale">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                    <h2>Be there or be square!</h2>
                    <p>Buy your tickets by clicking the button</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <button class="btn-primary btn">BUY</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="title">Line-up</h1>
            <hr />
            <!--
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="artist col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <img src="img/unknowndj.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                    <h4 class="text-center">DJ Contest</h4>
                    <p class="text-center">21.00 - 22.00</p>
                    <button class="btn-primary btn" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;">JOIN!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            -->
            
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="artist col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="backgroundgreen">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Audiophonic/" target="_blank"><img src="img/artist2.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="text-center">Audiophonic</h4>
                    <p class="text-center">22.00 - 23.00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="artist col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="backgroundgreen">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Freaquency.Ghent/" target="_blank"><img src="img/artist3.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="text-center">Frequency</h4>
                    <p class="text-center">23.00 - 00.00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="artist col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="backgroundgreen">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/lesmecsmusic/" target="_blank"><img src="img/artist4.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="text-center">Les Mecs</h4>
                    <p class="text-center">00.00 - 01.00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="artist col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="backgroundgreen">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/DjMaoriOfficial/" target="_blank"><img src="img/artist5.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="text-center">Maori</h4>
                    <p class="text-center">01.00 - 02.00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="artist col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="backgroundgreen">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/VertigoMusicOfficial/" target="_blank"><img src="img/artist6.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="text-center">Vertigo</h4>
                    <p class="text-center">02.00 - 03.00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="artist col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="backgroundgreen">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Official.David.D/" target="_blank"><img src="img/artist7.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="text-center">David D</h4>
                    <p class="text-center">03.00 - 04.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </section>

    <section  id="partners">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Partners</h1>
            <hr class="container" />
            <p>We absolutely love our partners! Every year, they help us in making this wonderful event become a reality.</p>
            <p>Take a look:</p>
            <div id="imgpartners" class="col-md-12">
                <img src="img/entrepot.png" class="img-responsive col-md-3 col-sm-6"/>
                <img src="img/jdb.png" class="img-responsive col-md-3 col-sm-6"/>
                <img src="img/stad.png" class="img-responsive col-md-3 col-sm-6"/>
                <img src="img/texlab.png" class="img-responsive col-md-3 col-sm-6" id="tex"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="tickets" class="container">
        <h1>Tickets</h1>
        <hr/>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="img/GLOW2017-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:20px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FGlowITDark%2Fvideos%2F653548701490325%2F&show_text=1&width=560" width="560" height="489" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
            <div id="text">
                <h2>Have you seen last year's aftermovie?</h2>
                <p>You better be a part of our next edition!</p>
                <button class="btn-primary btn">Buy tickets</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="" id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 style="color:white;">Contact</h1>
            <hr />
            <form action="contact.php" method="post">
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield is-upgraded" data-upgraded=",MaterialTextfield">
                    <!--<label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>-->
                    <input placeholder="Name" name="name" class="form-control" type="text" id="name">
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield is-upgraded" data-upgraded=",MaterialTextfield">
                    <!--<label class="control-label" for="email">email</label>-->
                    <input placeholder="Email" name="email" class="form-control" type="email" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield is-upgraded" data-upgraded=",MaterialTextfield">
                    <!--<label class="control-label" for="subject">subject</label>-->
                    <input placeholder="Subject" name="subject" class="form-control" type="text" id="subject">
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield is-upgraded" data-upgraded=",MaterialTextfield">
                    <!--<label class="control-label" for="message">Message</label>-->
                    <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" class="form-control" type="text" rows="3" id="message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-upgraded=",MaterialButton,MaterialRipple">
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="">
        <div class="footercontent">
            <img src="img/GITD.png" class="col-xs-12 img-responsive" id="logofooter"/>
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="sm">
                <ul class="col-xs-12">
                    <li class="col-xs-1"></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-2"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/GlowITDark/" target="_blank"><img src="img/fb2.jpg" /></a></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-2"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/glowinthedarkbe/" target="_blank"><img class="" src="img/insta.jpg" /></a></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-2"><a href="https://twitter.com/GITDevent" target="_blank"><img class="" src="img/twitter.jpg" /></a></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-2"><a><img class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" src="img/snapchat.jpg" /></a></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-2"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvV_UIcSjejxCl_tMfrIIEA" target="_blank"><img class="" src="img/yt.jpg" /></a></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-1"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add us on Snapchat!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img src="img/snapcode.png" class="img-responsive" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for anyone wanting to see the site and have a look in my code: www.gitd.be

Comment: The error you mention `untellisense undefined`, there is no use of `untellisense` anywhere in your code.

Comment: So I should just take it out?

Comment: can you minimise your code ?

Comment: I was also thinking, maybe it's because I didn't specify a viewport?
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">